# Axios delete method gives error 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make a delete button works in my React app. I separate the axios code in a separate module, `persons.js` to make the code more cleaner in `App.js`. Below are the delete function logic, where it is use in the code, an extracted `persons.js` file, and `Person` component.

My code works fine in browser but when I click the delete button, I keep on getting errors saying 'DELETE http://localhost:3001/persons/undefined 404 (Not Found)'. I see there are problems with the `id` not being able to get identified but I have already included it in the `persons.js` in the `deletePerson` function. I also have already included `key={person.id}` in
`Person` component.

`<Person key={person.id} person={person}  deleteButton={()=>handleDelete(index)} text='Delete' />`

I also tried changing index in `Person` component above to `{person.id}` but it still not working. How can I fix this ?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import personService from './services/persons'
import Person from './components/Person'

.......

const handleDelete = (index) => {
    const newPerson = persons.filter((_, id) => id !== index)

    personService
      .delete()
      .then(response=> {
        setPersons(newPerson.concat(response.data))
    })
  }
```

and it is used here in `Person` component

```
 <ul>
  {persons.filter((person) => {
    if (searchTerm === "") {
    return person
  } else if (person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
    return person
  }
  }).map((person, index) => {
    return (
    <Person key={person.id} person={person}  deleteButton={()=>handleDelete(index)} text='Delete' />
  );
  })
  }
  </ul>
```

Person component used above

```
import React from "react";

const Person = ({person, deleteButton, text}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <li> 
          {person.name} {person.number}
          <button onClick={deleteButton}> {text} </button> 
        </li>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Person
```

persons.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/persons'

const getAll = () => {
  return axios.get(baseUrl)
}

const create = newObject => {
  return axios.post(baseUrl, newObject)
}

const update = (id, newObject) => {
  return axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, newObject)
}

const deletePerson = (id) => {
  return axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`)
}


export default { 
  getAll: getAll, 
  create: create, 
  update: update,
  delete: deletePerson
}
```

Comment: shouln't it be `deleteButton={()=>handleDelete(person.id)}` ?

Comment: @Kaneki21 I just tried it but the same error still persist

Comment: Use Typescript and you won't make mistakes like this... `personService.delete(index)`

Comment: @Phil it's working now but the delete button remains as i click it and there are warning in the browser saying 'each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop'.  only after I refresh the page then it returns to normal but great the data has been deleted . btw i'm planning to learn ts soon after I finish this mern stack

Comment: @JabriJuhinin I want to know that why are you concating the response on delete to your PersonList. what is the response of the delete api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your function call in Person component

```
<Person key={person.id} person={person}  deleteButton={()=>handleDelete(person.id)} text='Delete' />
```

now we are passing `person.id` in `handleDelete` function so we need to change the function like following

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
const newPerson = persons.filter((person) => person.id !== id)

personService
  .delete(id)
  .then(response=> {
    setPersons(newPerson.concat(response.data))
})
}
```

Comment: it was a mistake. i've change it to setPersons(newPerson)